# Free .NET x86/x64 debugging library or tool for a custom C# IDE?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm building a code editor that needs to provide basic debugging functionality - i.e. my software needs to act as a debugger, debugging .NET libraries that it produced that will run (mainly) under various versions of the full .NET desktop framework. It needs to be able to debug both x86 as well as x64 applications.

Is there any good recent software or library providing debugging functionality?

Microsoft's mDBG sample is pretty good, but very old by now and is surely missing some of the more recent debugging interface features.

I've also stumbled upon Microsofts "VSDBG" tool, which I *think* is what Visual Studio Code uses for its .NET debugging.
But then again, it seems you're only allowed to run this in conjunction with Microsoft products (Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code). Also there is next to no information on this available. And it only seems to debug x64 processes at the moment I believe.

Is there any other library or method anyone could recommend?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy). It is a decompiler that includes a debugger.

- License: GPLv3
- can debug both x64 and x86 (via separate executables)
- supports breakpoints, locals, watch window, breaking on exceptions
- is actively developed at the moment

[image]